# What's the most reliable way to store user data when a user is temporarily redirected to another site?

Tags: php

I am integrating  payment gateway(SecurePay) into my website i'm building and when the customer clicks the checkout button they are redirected to a secure SecurePay page where they can enter their credit card details and then automatically redirected back to my website with some POST data so i can generate an invoice etc. Though it's only limited data, like whether it's approved or not, the total amount, surcharges. etc but no addresses or anything similar, there's actually no option to parse in any cold holder data like that.

So i was thinking to store card holder data in a SESSION variable, but i'm worried if for what ever reason the session is somehow destroyed or times out as the customer is entering their card details.

Is it better to use cookies to store this data?

I could store it in SQL but i don't really want to store a bunch of data i don't need, that and data security requirements suggest not to keep any card holder data you don't need anyway. I could delete the DB entries as soon as the invoice is generated but seems like a a bit of unnecessary work.

I have read a few posts about this, most seem to say use sessions or store in SQL, is it really the best option though?

Comment: Store in db but don't store sensitive information there. There's a transaction id that you can identify if the user has paid anything or not.

Comment: many options there, session, cookie, browser storage but for such sensitive information, info should be saved on server side. Better if you save info in temp db table or create your own table where save info temporarily and then after successful complition or cancelation, delete record

Comment: Okay, seems like the DB is the go, thank you both